# How to debug in vscode already compiled executable?

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When trying to debug in vscode, the vscode generate `launch.json` config file. When I try to debug, it first tries to compile the source and then debug the exe. I would like to just debug already compiled executable (compiled with `gcc -g` option).

The json file is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc-10 - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [
                "-pthread",
                "common.c"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc-10 build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I make somehow the vsode to *not* compile but just debug *with* already compiled source to `"program":"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"`, I have compiled to the very same name - no extension in current directory, as the property suggest. So how to make vscode to take this executable as its debug file?

Comment: Remove the `"preLaunchTask"`?

Comment: Well yes, that will not pre-compile, but then the debugger has no usage, since the debugger will not load *local-vairables* which is needed when debugging, so that didn't fully solve the problem

Comment: That sounds like you compiled your application without debug symbols (`-g` flag for GCC) or with optimization turned on. You can't have a "normal" debug experience if you don't compile specifically for it

Answer (score 0):

I'm using google tests for testing my application layer. But I also needed step through debugging of my tests when they fail.

Here is my launch.json generated by vscode with some minor tweaks

```
 {
        "name": "Debug debug_test",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test/build/app/debug/logging_test.exe",
        "args": [
            "${cmake.testArgs}"
        ],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is executed with the run and debug toolbar on vscode. Im using a ninja build script, with cmake. cmake is using the ninja-multicondig generator. Compiler is from msys2 websitesite. Also there is a .exe and .pdb within the folder. I think both are needed.